# Is there a 3rd party app to change the subdocument location in a Word 2007 master document?

Tags: microsoft-word, hyperlink

We have had the unenviable happen: various master documents refer to sub-documents that are no longer where they used to be due to a directory renaming. Is there a 3rd party app which can be used to tweak the HYPERLINK field without losing the master/sub-document relationship?

Comment: I just found a workaround! Save in XML, edit the XML, reopen in Word. Still, I'd be interested in a less involved way of solving the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save in XML, edit the XML, reopen in Word.